# The symmetric group and the field with one element

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, field-with-one-element

I've heard a few times that the symmetric group is an algebraic group over a field with one element, and that the alternating group is quite specifically $SO_n(\mathbb{F}_1)$. This does make a lot of sense intuitively, and actually helps to explain to non-specialists the relations between different things I have done.

However, objects over the (non-existent) field with one element aren't just a metaphor - they are objects that can be defined properly, though that may not have happened *yet*. What is the status for the correspondence between $Alt(n)$ and $SO_n(\mathbb{F}_1)$? Is there really a well-defined homomorphism of some sort, and, if so, are there references where this is worked out?

Comment: Are you sure it is $SO_n(F_1)$ and not $SL_n(F_1)$? The latter would make sense if you consider buildings associated with algebraic groups over $F_q$: Cardinality of $F_q$ gives you thickness of the building. Setting $q=1$ gives you thin buildings, i.e., apartments. One then can argue that the "algebraic group" corresponding to the thin building is just the Weyl group. 

Comment: Does http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.3824.pdf answer your question?

Comment: By the way, I would not say that $\mathbb{F}_1$ is non-existent. In fact, there are already *many* precise definitions. The problem is that there is no prefered one, and up to know no theory has led to a proof of the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: As Martin's arXiv link points out, the basic idea goes back to early work by Tits following Chevalley's 1955 Tohoku paper.  In this setting, Tits suggested that the Weyl group `$W$` attached to a *Chevalley group* (split simple algebraic group) over a finite field would have a degenerate BN-pair (and Bruhat decomposition) involving just `$W$` if one allowed the field to have only one element.   This philosophy is consistent with the way Tits developed buildings, using copies of the Weyl/Coxeter complex of `$W$`.   The symmetric group is just one example.

Comment: @Z254R: Such question will be surely closed as "subjective and argumentative."

Comment: It is not the anger of the Gods of mathematics that we fear. It is the chaos of people arguing subjectively, in what ought to be an orderly forum, over the merits of inconclusive citations.

Comment: @Z254R: those two citations do not exist! I admit that I really don't get what you meant...